# Aspect instantiation in AspectJ with pertypewithin

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm trying to do a singleton pattern using AspectJ and the clause **pertypewithin**.

This is for educational purpose to fully understand the clause, i already did this using other techniques but i can't make it work as i wish.

```
package resourceManager;



//For every Type that extends resource
public aspect ResourcePool pertypewithin(resource+) {
    //The resource      
    public Object cached;



Object around(Object instance): execution( *.new(..))&&!within(resource)&&this(instance){
    if(cached==null)
        {
        proceed(instance);
        cached=instance;
        }


    System.out.println(instance+" "+ cached);

    return cached;
}       




}
```

My problem is that at the end i return cached but the new object in my main function will hold the value of instance. Inside the aspect it behaves as it should: the first time i instantiate a resource, cached and instance will hold the same value, the secondo time, they will differ.

```
instance: resourceManager.RB@4ffac352 cached: resourceManager.RB@4ffac352
instance: resourceManager.RB@582d6583 cached: resourceManager.RB@4ffac352
```

But when i print the 2 new objects, this happens:

```
resourceManager.RB@4ffac352
resourceManager.RB@582d6583
```

Comment: Can you include the entire program here?  Hard to understand what is happening without seeing the main method.  It also looks like your sample program output does not match what you have in your sample code.

Comment: Another comment.  Your question title is misleading.  pertypewithin does not make a singleton aspect.  Singleton aspects are only created when there is no per-clause in the aspect declaration.  If I am understanding your question correctly, you should be asking "Aspect instantiation in AspectJ with pertypewithin".

Answer (score 0):

I just found this old question today after it was edited lately.

What you want is a caching solution based on `pertypewithin`. While the idea is nice, there is one technical problem: You cannot return an object from an `around() : execution(*.new(..))` advice because the object in question is not fully instantiated yet and the around advice implicitly returns `void`. Try for yourself and change the advice return type to `void` and do not return anything. It works - surprise, surprise! ;-)

So what can you do instead? Use `around() : call(*.new(..))` instead in order to manipulate the result of a constructor call. You can even skip object creation altogether by not calling `proceed()` from there.

There are several ways to utilise this in order to make your resource objects cached singletons. But because you specifically asked for a `pertypewithin` use case, I am going to choose a solution involving this type of aspect instantiation. The drawback here is that you need to combine two aspects in order to achieve the desired outcome.

**Sample resource classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.resource;

public class Foo {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.resource;

public class Bar {}
```

**Driver application creating multiple instances of each resource type:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.resource.Bar;
import de.scrum_master.resource.Foo;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Foo());
        System.out.println(new Foo());
        System.out.println(new Bar());
        System.out.println(new Bar());
    }
}
```

**Modified version of resource pool aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.resourceManager;

public aspect ResourcePool pertypewithin(de.scrum_master.resource..*) {
    private Object cached;

    after(Object instance) : execution(*.new(..)) && this(instance) {
        // Not necessary because SingletonAspect only proceeds for 'cache == null' 
        //if (cached != null) return;
        cached = instance;
        System.out.println("Cached instance = " + cached);
    }

    public Object getCachedInstance() {
        return cached;
    }
}
```

**Aspect skipping object over object creation and returning cached objects:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.resourceManager;

public aspect SingletonAspect {
    Object around() : call(de.scrum_master.resource..*.new(..)) {
        Object cached = ResourcePool
            .aspectOf(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType())
            .getCachedInstance();
        return cached == null ? proceed() : cached;
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Cached instance = de.scrum_master.resource.Foo@5caf905d
de.scrum_master.resource.Foo@5caf905d
de.scrum_master.resource.Foo@5caf905d
Cached instance = de.scrum_master.resource.Bar@8efb846
de.scrum_master.resource.Bar@8efb846
de.scrum_master.resource.Bar@8efb846
```